# Python requests 'Connection aborted.' if it will started with a cronjob

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, python-requests

If i start my python file normally it works. but if i start it with cron the `('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))` error appears on all requests.

you can see my cron configuration on my question before. but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Looking into my crystal ball, I see your problem is on line 57.

Comment: @JohnGordon see in my crystal ball https://imgur.com/ZDzgATc .  I made this image long time ago :)

Answer (score 3):

`cron` jobs execute in a different environment (and usually shell) to that in which a user logged into a terminal would have. This means that environment variables that may be declared when you are logged in may not be declared, or might have different values, for cron.

The error that `requests` reports relates to resolving hostnames into IP addresses, and that often means a DNS configuration issue.

So look for any environment variables that are declared in your terminal environment that are not set for cron. These could be `LOCALDOMAIN` or `RES_OPTIONS`, but there might be others depending on your DNS set up. There is some information in the [resolv.conf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html) man page.

You can find out what the cron environment is by setting up a test cron job that dumps the environment to a file:

```
MM HH * * * env > ~/cron_env
```

changing MM and HH to some soon to occur minutes and hours. Then inspect the contents of the file `~/cron_env` and compare it to that of your user.

Comment: the problem was because on boot linux doesn't has an ip. i wait for network service is up.